# Looking for circuit, reversing polarity of DC motor

Tags: usb, circuit-design, reverse-polarity

Consider I have 2 inputs, A and B.
**I need help with a circuit that does the following**
if only A is active (A,B : 1,0), then the motor should run clockwise
if only B is active (A,B : 0,1), then the motor should run anti-clockwise.
for other situations, let the motor be in off state..
I'm using a raspberry pi's GPIO pins to send inputs ( i.e. A and B)

Also, since I'm using a power bank, i would like to know is there any way or a device that converts usb port to get Vcc and GND terminals.

The DC motor I have is the ones usually found in toys, maybe called miniature low torque flat motor, and the power bank I have has 3 USB ports,5V 2A, 5V 1A, 5V 1A.

Comment: that appears to be two unrelated questions ... please delete one and post separately

Comment: the two relay motor drive/reversing circuit seems like what you want,

Comment: The "H" configuation is classic to drive motors in either direction.

Comment: https://geextor.com/2016/11/20/driving-a-dc-motor-with-raspberry-pi/ https://www.adafruit.com/product/3628